# Is there a way to delete an app of an iPad that used the same Apple ID without touching it?

Tags: ipad, applications, apple-id

My relative yelled at me for downloading an app for my friend now I have to delete it but there's no way I can ask my friend if she could delete the app and look for someone else to download it for her (Minecraft). I can't take her iPad and delete it so how can I delet it without touching the iPad. Is there a way? Mine is iPad Pro, hers is iPad Air 2.

Answer (score 2):

It's bought & paid for - you own it forever, you can't send it back.

If you can't physically delete it from your friend's iPad, then there's no way to remove it. They won't ever be able to update it without knowing your Apple ID log & pass, but it will remain until they choose to delete it.

Removing it from any/all other devices will not affect that one.